# Sound not coming through on iOS push notifications in ionic 4

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic4

We're using this guide to create a pretty routine push notification system.

We have everything working and push notifications are coming through. On Android, the push notifications make the default alert sound. On iOS however, no sound is made.

How can we configure the push notification to use the default alert sound on iOS (we don't want to create/manage a custom alert sound).

I've already configured the presentationOptions setting in the capacitor.config.json file.

```
{
  "appId": "REDACTED",
  "appName": "REDACTED",
  "bundledWebRuntime": false,
  "npmClient": "npm",
  "webDir": "www",
  "plugins": {
    "PushNotifications": {
      "presentationOptions": ["badge", "sound", "alert"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this ,

```
"PushNotifications": {
      "presentationOptions": ["badge", "sound", "alert"]
    }
```

The problem is that it doesnot work properly in all phones . Most of the time sound was not working . sSometimes you have to enable sound from the app detail , sometimes it worked noramlly .